# Linux: Run X Window System at startup and show only terminal emulator with login prompt?

Tags: linux, xorg

I'd like to know how easy/hard it is to achieve this:

When my system starts, it should automatically start X Window System on tty7 (or any tty), and should run a terminal emulator (xterm, or if possible, more fancy one like Tilix) inside it. The terminal emulator should run as a non-root user with minimal privileges to prevent potential security risk. Inside the terminal emulator it should run `login` to show the same login prompt that shows on tty1 to tty6 automatically.

Notes:

Usually if I install any desktop system, it loads a greeter on system startup in tty7. I hope not to have the greeter. The system is very old and I'd like to save resource where possible, but I still want to have some mouse and font/emoji support.

If this is not possible, what is the most lightweight way to achieve something similar?